# Return total balance from unsorted purchase items that may have specials

Tags: f#

This is in reference to the following [kata](http://codekata.com/kata/kata09-back-to-the-checkout/):

```
  Item   Unit      Special
         Price     Price
  --------------------------
    A     50       3 for 130
    B     30       2 for 45
    C     20
    D     15
```

I am still trying to learn F#.
Thus, I have the following code:

```
module Checkout

(*Types*)
type Type = A | B | C | D
type Total = { UnitPrice:int ; Qty:int }
             member x.Price() = x.UnitPrice * x.Qty

type Special =
    | None
    | ThreeForOneThirty
    | TwoForFourtyFive

type Item = 
    { Type:Type
      Total:Total
      Special:Special } 

      member x.Price() =
        match x.Special with
        | ThreeForOneThirty -> 
            if x.Total.Qty / 3 > 0
            then (x.Total.Qty / 3) * 130
            else x.Total.Price()

        | TwoForFourtyFive ->
            if x.Total.Qty / 2 > 0
            then (x.Total.Qty / 2) * 45
            else x.Total.Price()

        | None -> x.Total.Price()

(*Private Functions*)
let private getTypeQty itemsOfType = 
    itemsOfType |> Seq.sumBy(fun x -> x.Total.Qty)

let private consolidate group acc =

    let first = group |> Seq.head
    { Type    =  first.Type; 
      Total   = { Qty=group |> getTypeQty; UnitPrice=first.Total.UnitPrice }
      Special = first.Special; } :: acc 

(*Tests*)
open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let ``buying (2) A units, (1) B unit, (1) A unit = $160`` () =

    // Setup
    let a2 = { Type=A; Total={UnitPrice=50; Qty=2}; Special=ThreeForOneThirty }
    let b =  { Type=B; Total={UnitPrice=30; Qty=1}; Special=TwoForFourtyFive  }
    let a =  { Type=A; Total={UnitPrice=50; Qty=1}; Special=ThreeForOneThirty }

    seq [a2; b; a] |> Seq.groupBy (fun item -> item.Type)
                   |> Seq.map snd
                   |> Seq.fold(fun consolidated group -> consolidate group consolidated) []
                   |> Seq.sumBy (fun item -> item.Price())
                   |> should equal 160
```

I don't like the way I coupled the Specials DU to an item. Thus, my implementation enables an item to reference any special. It just feels wrong...

Comment: Is this actually correct? If I bought 3 units of B, I'd expect it to cost 75, whereas I think this would charge me 90.

Comment: @BenAaronson If you buy 3 units of B, you get 3/2*45, eg. 1*45, so 45, not 90. (Because `/` is integer division.) So there's indeed a bug, and the fix is to use `(x.Total.Qty / 2) * 45  + (x.Total.Qty % 2) * x.Total.UnitPrice` which gives 75 as expected.

Comment: @QuentinPradet Ah yeah, well spotted

Answer (score 23):

Paraphrasing Kent Beck (IIRC), I'd design my types so that concerns that change together are kept together, whereas concerns that change separately should be kept as separate as possible.

With that in mind, I'd start defining shopping basket items as simply as possible:

```
type Good = { SKU : string; Price : int }
```

This also enables you to define the price table, independently of the discount rules:

```
let prices = [
    { SKU = "A"; Price = 50 }
    { SKU = "B"; Price = 30 }
    { SKU = "C"; Price = 20 }
    { SKU = "D"; Price = 15 } ]

// string -> Good option
let scan sku = prices |> List.tryFind (fun x -> x.SKU = sku)
```

This code snippet also defines a simple `scan` function that can be used to look up a string in the price table in order to turn it into a `Good` value.

I don't think modelling the product as a discriminated union (e.g. `A | B | C | D`) is a good idea, because that's going to make it hard if you want to add an `E` product, or if you want to remove the `C` product.

The same type of argument goes for price rules. List prices change according to business decisions, and the same goes for discounts, but at different rates. Discriminated unions define a finite set of options, but I don't think a set of discounts ought to be a finite set of hard-coded options. You should be able to add or remove discount rules according to business decisions.

Instead, I'd be inclined to define a discount with the type `Good list -> int * Good list`. The idea here is that you input a list of `Good` values, and you get back a price (`int`) and the remaining `Good` values where a price has yet to be calculated.

You can, for example, implement the rule about the `A` products like this:

```
// Good list -> int * Good list
let aRule items =
    let xs, others = List.partition (fun x -> x.SKU = "A") items
    let hits, rest =
        xs |> List.chunkBySize 3 |> List.partition (fun l -> l.Length = 3)
    let xTotal = hits.Length * 130
    xTotal, rest |> List.concat |> List.append others
```

This looks, perhaps, a bit complicated, but it works like this:

1. First, it partitions all items into `A` items (`xs`) and all other items (`others`).
2. It then divides `xs` into chunks of 3. This produces a list of lists, where most of the lists have the length 3. There may, however, be a residual list with one or two items, so these are partitioned into the `rest` value.
3. The total for all the `hits` is calculated. Each hit is a list of three `A` items, which has the special discount price `130`. You may have three, six, nine, etc. `A` items, so the special price `130` is multiplied with the length of `hits`, which is a list of lists.
4. Finally, `xTotal` is returned, together with all the items that didn't trigger the discount. These include all non-`A` items, but also residual `A` items.

Likewise, the discount for `B` items can be defined in the same way:

```
// Good list -> int * Good list
let bRule items =
    let xs, others = List.partition (fun x -> x.SKU = "B") items
    let hits, rest =
        xs |> List.chunkBySize 2 |> List.partition (fun l -> l.Length = 2)
    let xTotal = hits.Length * 45
    xTotal, rest |> List.concat |> List.append others
```

This function is almost identical to `aRule`, so is a candidate for some refactoring. Here, however, I decided to apply the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)), so I left them as is.

Apart from these discount rules, you'll also need a 'default' price calculation rule:

```
// Good list -> int * 'a list
let defaultRule items = List.sumBy (fun x -> x.Price) items, []
```

Notice how `Good list -> int * 'a list` also fits the desired type of `Good list -> int * Good list`. This enables you to define a set of rules as a list:

```
// (Good list -> int * Good list) list
let rules = [aRule; bRule; defaultRule]
```

Calculating a total price is now easy:

```
// ('a -> int * 'a) list -> 'a -> int
let total rules items = 
    let acc (tot, rest) f =
        let tot', rest' = f rest
        tot + tot', rest'
    rules |> List.fold acc (0, items) |> fst
```

This function performs a *left fold* over `rules`, while accumulating the total so far, and the rest of the items.

## Tests

This implementation passes all the tests in the [original kata formulation](http://codekata.com/kata/kata09-back-to-the-checkout):

```
open Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Theory>]
[<InlineData("", 0)>]
[<InlineData("A", 50)>]
[<InlineData("AB", 80)>]
[<InlineData("CDBA", 115)>]

[<InlineData("AA", 100)>]
[<InlineData("AAA", 130)>]
[<InlineData("AAAA", 180)>]
[<InlineData("AAAAA", 230)>]
[<InlineData("AAAAAA", 260)>]

[<InlineData("AAAB", 160)>]
[<InlineData("AAABB", 175)>]
[<InlineData("AAABBD", 190)>]
[<InlineData("DABABA", 190)>]

// Incremental
[<InlineData("A", 50)>]
[<InlineData("AB", 80)>]
[<InlineData("ABA", 130)>]
[<InlineData("ABAA", 160)>]
[<InlineData("ABAAB", 175)>]
let ``total returns correct result`` (items : string) expected =
    let actual =
        items |> Seq.choose (string >> scan) |> Seq.toList |> total rules
    expected =! actual
```

## Flexibility

Is this the simplest possible implementation? Most likely not, but it's fairly flexible.

Imagine, for example, that you're being asked to implement a new 'bundle' discount where you get `A`, `B`, and `C` for `85` if you buy them together. You can implement this without changing any of the existing code:

```
// f:('a -> bool) -> ('a list -> 'a option * 'a list)
let tryFindFirst f =
    let acc (found, others) x =
        match found with
        | Some hit -> Some hit, x :: others
        | None -> if f x then Some x, others else None, x :: others
    List.fold acc (None, []) >> (fun (found, others) -> found, List.rev others)

// Good list -> int * Good list
let bundleRule items =
    let aOpt, rest = tryFindFirst (fun x -> x.SKU = "A") items
    let bOpt, rest = tryFindFirst (fun x -> x.SKU = "B") rest
    let cOpt, rest = tryFindFirst (fun x -> x.SKU = "C") rest
    match aOpt, bOpt, cOpt with
    | Some a, Some b, Some c -> 85, rest
    | _ -> 0, items
```

As you can see, `bundleRule` has the desired type, so can be used together with the other pricing rules:

```
[<Theory>]
[<InlineData("ABC", 85)>]
[<InlineData("BAC", 85)>]
[<InlineData("ABBA", 145)>]
[<InlineData("ABCAA", 185)>]
let ``bundle rule is applied correctly when having high priority``
    (items : string)
    expected =

    let actual =
        items
        |> Seq.choose (string >> scan)
        |> Seq.toList
        |> total (bundleRule :: rules)
    expected =! actual
```

Notice the test case for `ABCAA`. This combination fits both the bundle discount, and the triple-`A` discount. Since `bundleRule` comes first, however, it wins, and removes `ABC` from further calculation, thereby correctly preventing the triple-`A` rule from being applied.

If your business experts ask you to prioritise the triple-`A` rule over the bundle rule, that's possible as well:

```
[<Theory>]
[<InlineData("ABC", 85)>]
[<InlineData("BAC", 85)>]
[<InlineData("ABBA", 145)>]
[<InlineData("ABCAA", 180)>]
let ``bundle rule is applied correctly when having low priority``
    (items : string)
    expected =

    let actual =
        items
        |> Seq.choose (string >> scan)
        |> Seq.toList
        |> total [aRule; bRule; bundleRule; defaultRule]
    expected =! actual
```

In this test, notice that the order of the rules is different. This causes `aRule` to trigger before `bundleRule`, and for that reason, the `ABCAA` test case has a different outcome.

## State

Did I just come up with all of this myself? Not quite, I was leveraging my knowledge of functional programming 'design patterns'.

Functions with the type `'s -> 'a * 's` are part of the **State monad**. All the price functions have the type `Good list -> int * Good list`, which make them State 'instances'.

In fact, you can make use of the state monad easier by introducing the standard monadic functions like *return*, *bind*, *map*, and so on. In F#, you can further sprinkle on syntactic sugar by implementing a `state` computation expression. Here are some notes on doing that.

Sometimes, it helps to define a type alias for the monadic type in question:

```
type State<'a, 's> = ('s -> 'a * 's)
```

This isn't strictly necessary, but I think it makes is a bit easier to reason about some of the following code.

Next, you can define a module to implement the most important functions:

```
module State =
    // 'a -> State<'b,'a> -> 'b * 'a
    let run state (f : State<_, _>) = f state

    // 'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b
    let lift x state = x, state

    // ('a -> 'b) -> State<'a,'c> -> 'c -> 'b * 'c
    let map f x state =
        let x', newState = run state x
        f x', newState

    // ('a -> State<'b,'s>) -> State<'a,'s> -> 's -> 'b * 's    
    let bind (f : 'a -> State<'b, 's>) (x : State<'a, 's>) state =
        let x', newState = run state x
        run newState (f x')

    // 'a -> 'a * 'a    
    let get state = state, state

    // 'a -> 'b -> unit * 'a
    let put newState _ = (), newState

    // ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> unit * 'a)
    let modify f = get |> map f |> bind put
```

You can define more, but here, I only added the functions I'll need in the coming examples.

The most important functions are `lift` and `bind`. Often, in other languages, the `lift` function is called `return`, or `pure`, but both of these are reserved keywords in F#. These two functions define the monad. The rest are useful extra functions (apart from the `map` function, which could be used to define State as a `Functor` in Haskell).

## Computation expression

Using the functions in the `State` module, you can implement a computation expression builder for the State monad. Again, I only add the absolute minimum required in order to make the examples below compile:

```
type StateBuilder () =
    // State<'c,'d> * ('c -> State<'e,'d>) -> ('d -> 'e * 'd)
    member this.Bind (s, f) = State.bind f s
    // 'a -> ('b -> 'a * 'b)
    member this.Return x = State.lift x
```

As you can see, the `Bind` and `Return` methods simply delegate to the `State` module's functions.

## Refactored price functions

With these new tools, you can now refactor the above price functions.

First, I decided to implement a single function that you can use to define *n for x* discounts:

```
// int -> int * string -> (Good list -> int * Good list)
let forOnly price (n, sku) = state {
    let! xs = List.partition (fun x -> x.SKU = sku)
    let hits, residual =
        xs |> List.chunkBySize n |> List.partition (fun l -> l.Length = n)
    do! State.modify (residual |> List.concat |> List.append)
    return hits.Length * price }
```

If you keep in mind the definition of the State type, you can also view this function as having the type `int -> int * string -> State<int, Good list>`. It can be used like this to define a price rule:

```
// Good list -> int * Good list  .. or, alternatively:
// State<int, Good list>
(3, "A") |> forOnly 130
```

Notice that it's possible to use the existing, built-in function `List.partition` with a `let!` binding. This is possible because the type of `List.partition` is `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list`. Notice how `'a list -> 'a list * 'a list` can also be viewed as `State<'a list, 'a list>`. This means that the first `let!` expression binds `xs` to the items that satisfy the predicate passed to `List.partition`, while the items that *don't* match are being threaded through the computation expression as the underlying state.

Once you've found any `residual`, you'll need to put it back into the underlying state. You can do this with `do! State.modify`. Finally, you `return` the result of the price calculation.

The same sort of refactoring can be done for `bundleRule`:

```
// Good list -> int * Good list
let bundleRule = state {
    let! originalItems = State.get
    let! aOpt = tryFindFirst (fun x -> x.SKU = "A")
    let! bOpt = tryFindFirst (fun x -> x.SKU = "B")
    let! cOpt = tryFindFirst (fun x -> x.SKU = "C")
    match aOpt, bOpt, cOpt with
    | Some a, Some b, Some c -> return 85
    | _ ->
        do! State.put originalItems
        return 0 }
```

Compared to the previous incarnation of `bundleRule`, this implementation is actually a bit longer, but IMO more readable. Again, the underlying state is implicitly threaded through the computation, but as you can tell, you can retrieve it with `State.get` and 'write' it with `State.put`.

I find this version more readable because I don't have to declare intermediary state values (`rest`) and pass them around. In the previous version, if I forgot to pass them around in the correct manner, the calculation would be incorrect.

It's almost as though the State-based implementation looks more imperative. The same would be the case in Haskell, and there's a saying that *Haskell is the* best *imperative language that exists*. Here we see that F# is no slouch either.

Answer (score 9):

### Changing the data structure

You're right to worry about the data structures. As Linus Torvals said:

> git actually has a simple design, with stable and reasonably well-documented data structures. In fact, I'm a huge proponent of designing your code around the data, rather than the other way around, and I think it's one of the reasons git has been fairly successful […] I will, in fact, claim that the difference between a bad programmer and a good one is whether he considers his code or his data structures more important.

This is even more true in F# where pattern matching lets you really write code around your data structures. So, what's wrong here?

1. As you've noticed, allowing any Item Type to refer to any Special feels somewhat wrong because it's an error that a good data structure should be able to prevent.
2. You're repeating yourself a lot in `Item.Price()`: you have the same code with only values that change!

Those are two signs that you should not use `TwoForFourtyFive` but store the values as integers. You've already did that in `Total`, I'm sure you'll be able to do it for `Special` too. :)

### Smaller local issues

Now that the main issue is out, let's look at smaller local ones.

1. Comment should not be obvious.

   ```
   (*Private Functions*)
   ```

   This comment is not terribly useful, we can notice by ourselves that the functions are private. However, I do agree that for a simple file like this this separates the different sections quite nicely.
2. F# allows you to be concise in ways other languages don't:

   ```
   let private getTypeQty itemsOfType = 
       itemsOfType |> Seq.sumBy(fun x -> x.Total.Qty)
   ```

   You don't need to mention specify `itemsOfType`, and can write the function like this:

   ```
   let private getTypeQty = Seq.sumBy(fun x -> x.Total.Qty)
   ```
3. I would not recommend using `Seq` here - it's less efficient than List for small collections of elements and `Seq.head` is way slower and less natural than `List.head`
4. `fold` sends the accumulator first, so you should not fight, but accept it, by writing:

   ```
   let private consolidate acc group = ...
   ```

   which lets you call fold like this:

   ```
   |> Seq.fold consolidate []
   ```

The code won't be perfect after those changes, but we're getting there! I think the data structure would still need work, because while `Item.Price()` is now fine, `consolidate` will still be weird in the sense that it only looks at `first.Type` and `first.Special` and discards the rest. Just like `TwoForFourtyFive`, it works, but it's a code smell.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! I applied your feedback and my code looks a lot better now. I really appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to F# my self so maybe I'm wrong by meaning that your use of union types is a little overdone (as an exercise - ok).
Below I'm using an optional special price function (SpecialOffer) on the Product type and the total of each Product is calculated by Product.Total. My goal was to make the overall design a little more flexible:

```
// Function prototype
type SpecialOffer = int -> float -> float

type Product (name : string, unitPrice : float, specialOffer : SpecialOffer option) = 
  member this.Name = name
  member this.UnitPrice = unitPrice
  member this.SpecialOffer = specialOffer

  member this.Total units = 
    if this.SpecialOffer.IsSome then
      this.SpecialOffer.Value units this.UnitPrice
    else
      this.UnitPrice * (float units)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let products = [
    Product("A", 50.0, Some(fun n up -> (float(n / 3) * 130.0) + (float(n % 3) * up)));
    Product("B", 30.0, Some(fun n up -> (float(n / 2) * 45.0) + (float(n % 2) * up)));
    Product("C", 20.0, None);
    Product("D", 15.0, None)
  ]

  let buyProducts (productNames : string) = 
    seq { for ch in productNames do
            yield products |> Seq.find (fun p -> p.Name = ch.ToString())}


  let cart = buyProducts "DABABA"
  cart
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun p -> p)
  |> Seq.sumBy (fun pg -> (fst pg).Total((snd pg) |> Seq.length))
  |> printfn "%.2f"


  0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Let me write some simplifications to your code.

Comment: 1. Use `id` instead of `fun p -> p`

Comment: 2. Use `(fun (p,g) -> p.Total(g |> Seq.length))` instead of `(fun pg -> (fst pg).Total((snd pg) |> Seq.length))`

Comment: @FoggyFinder 0.) you're very welcome to :-)
1. I'm not sure, why you want to group by id instead of the type instance?

Comment: no, `id` it is function in F# which is equal to `fun p -> p` ;) [id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.id%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)